# How upload excel / xml file into oracle database

Tags: plsql

How to load XML / Excel data into table

Extracting the data from the document involves several steps. First the XML document must be parsed and a DOMDocument created from it. Once the DOMDocument is created the parser is no longer needed so it's resources can be freed.

Next the XPATH syntax is used to get a DOMNodeList containing all the EMP nodes.
Once we have the DOMNodeList we can loop through it getting the values for each node in turn. The values are returned using the XPATH sytax and placed in a table collection.

```
create or replace procedure proc_parseXml(pRawXMLdata clob)  is
   v_parser        Dbms_Xmlparser.Parser;
   v_Xml_Clob      Clob;
   v_Doc           Dbms_Xmldom.Domdocument;

   v_Child_Node    dbms_xmldom.domnodelist;
   v_xml_Node      Dbms_Xmldom.Domnode;


   v_empno         number;
   v_ename         varchar2(20);
   v_job           varchar2(20);
   v_hiredate      varchar2(20);

 Begin
      -- CLOB data

  v_Xml_Clob :=pRawXMLdata ;
   -- Create XML Parser.
    v_parser  := Dbms_Xmlparser.Newparser;
   -- Parse XML into DOM object                     
    Dbms_Xmlparser.Parseclob(v_parser , v_Xml_Clob);
   -- XML Document               
   v_Doc := Dbms_Xmlparser.Getdocument(v_parser );
   -- Root element
    v_Child_Node:=dbms_xslprocessor.selectNodes(dbms_xmldom.makeNode(v_doc),'/NewDataset/ExcelInfo');
   --
     For I in 0..dbms_xmldom.getlength(v_Child_Node)-1 LOOP
        v_xml_Node := dbms_xmldom.item(v_Child_Node,I);

        DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.valueof(v_xml_Node,'empno/text()',v_empno);
        DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.valueof(v_xml_Node,'ename/text()',v_ename);
        DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.valueof(v_xml_Node,'job/text()',v_job);
        DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.valueof(v_xml_Node,'hiredate/text()',v_hiredate);

        insert into emp(empno, ename, job, hiredate) values(v_empno,v_ename,v_job,v_hiredate);
   End LOOP;   



End;

/


--Call procedure proc_parseXml


declare
 v_rawXMLData clob;
begin
 v_rawXMLData :=  '<NewDataset> <ExcelInfo> <empno>7369</empno><ename>SMITH</ename> <job>CLERK</job> <hiredate>17-DEC-1980</hiredate> </employee>
     <employee><empno>7499</empno><ename>ALLEN</ename><job>SALESMAN</job><hiredate>20-FEB-1981</hiredate></ExcelInfo></NewDataset>';

proc_parseXml(v_rawXMLData );
end;

/
```

SELECT x.xml_data.getClobVal()
FROM   xml_tab x ;

---

Link for xml file
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/xmltable-convert-xml-data-into-rows-and-columns-using-sql
https://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/pkgs/dbms_xslprocessor.html#xslp11
[Uploaded data from xml file to oracle table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kexRC.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIPXA.gif)

Comment: Nice process description and supporting docs, so what is the question/issue you're trying to resolve? Please review the help section [ask].

Answer (score 0):

First create table HR_temp  and HR_temp_ERROR  and then create procedure.

After that call procedure with the required parameter.

```
create table HR_temp (col1 varchar2(20), col2 varchar2(20), col3 varchar2(20), col4 
varchar2(20), col5 varchar2(20), col6 varchar2(20), col7 varchar2(20),col8 
varchar2(20),col9 varchar2(20),col10 varchar2(20),col11 varchar2(20),col12 
varchar2(20),col13 varchar2(20),col14 varchar2(20));
```

/

```
  create table HR_temp_ERROR (ERROR varchar2(20), Status varchar2(20), col1 
   varchar2(20), col2 varchar2(20), col3 varchar2(20), col4 varchar2(20), col5 
   varchar2(20), col6 varchar2(20), col7 varchar2(20),col8 varchar2(20),col9 
   varchar2(20),col10 varchar2(20),col11 varchar2(20),col12 varchar2(20),col13 
    varchar2(20),col14 varchar2(20));
```

/

```
create or replace procedure proc_parseXml_new(pSessionId varchar2, pTransType 
   varchar2, pOperation varchar2, pRawXMLdata clob)  is
               v_parser        Dbms_Xmlparser.Parser;
               v_Xml_Clob      Clob;
               v_Doc           Dbms_Xmldom.Domdocument;

               v_Child_Node    dbms_xmldom.domnodelist;
               v_xml_Node      Dbms_Xmldom.Domnode;


               v_empno         number;
               v_ename         varchar2(20);
               v_job           varchar2(20);
               v_hiredate      varchar2(20);
               v_errorMsg      varchar2(20);

        Begin
              -- CLOB data

          v_Xml_Clob :=pRawXMLdata ;

          IF pOperation = 'RawUpload' THEN
               -- Create XML Parser.
               v_parser  := Dbms_Xmlparser.Newparser;
               -- Parse XML into DOM object                     
               Dbms_Xmlparser.Parseclob(v_parser , v_Xml_Clob);
               -- XML Document               
               v_Doc := Dbms_Xmlparser.Getdocument(v_parser );
               -- Root element
                v_Child_Node:=dbms_xslprocessor.selectNodes(dbms_xmldom.makeNode(v_doc),'/employees/employee');
               --
               For I in 0..dbms_xmldom.getlength(v_Child_Node)-1 LOOP
                    v_xml_Node := dbms_xmldom.item(v_Child_Node,I);

                    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.valueof(v_xml_Node,'empno/text()',v_empno);
                    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.valueof(v_xml_Node,'ename/text()',v_ename);
                    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.valueof(v_xml_Node,'job/text()',v_job);
                    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.valueof(v_xml_Node,'hiredate/text()',v_hiredate);

                    ---Validation Script---
                    If v_job='NA' Then 
                        v_errorMsg:= 'Job code should not be NA';
                        GOTO PrintError;
                    End if;

                    If v_hiredate is NULL Then 
                        v_errorMsg:='Hiredate cannot be blank';
                        GOTO PrintError;
                    End if;

                    insert into HR_temp(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,col6,col7) 
                    values (v_empno,v_ename,v_job,v_hiredate,pSessionId, pTransType, pOperation);

                    <<PrintError>>
                    insert into HR_temp_ERROR(Error,Status, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,col6,col7) 
                    values (v_errorMsg,'Failed',v_empno,v_ename,v_job,v_hiredate,pSessionId, pTransType, pOperation);


                End LOOP;   
         ELSE

            for I in
                    (select col1 EmpNo, col2 EName, col3 Job, col4 HireDate, col6 TransType from hr_temp
                    where pOperation='CommitUpload' and col5=pSessionId)
            loop

                If I.TransType='ADD' OR I.TransType='REMOVE AND ADD' THEN


                    insert into emp(empno, ename, job, hiredate) values(I.EmpNo,I.EName,I.Job,I.HireDate); 

                END IF;
            end loop;   



         END IF;


        End;

        /



 declare
    v_rawXMLData clob; 
    v_SessionId varchar2(20); 
    v_TransType varchar2(20); 
    v_Operation varchar2(20);
 begin
   v_TransType:='ADD';
   v_SessionId:='qwer1234';
    v_Operation:='RawUpload';


  v_rawXMLData :=  '<employees> <employee> <empno>7369</empno><ename>SMITH</ename> 
<job>CLERK</job> <hiredate>17-DEC-1980</hiredate> </employee>
    <employee><empno>7499</empno><ename>ALLEN</ename><job>SALESMAN</job><hiredate>20- 
 FEB-1981</hiredate></employee></employees>';


proc_parseXml_new(v_SessionId,  v_TransType, v_Operation , v_rawXMLData );
   end;

    /


       declare
            v_rawXMLData clob; 
            v_SessionId varchar2(20); 
            v_TransType varchar2(20); 
            v_Operation varchar2(20);
        begin
            v_TransType:='ADD';
            v_SessionId:='qwer1234';
            v_Operation:='RawUpload';


         v_rawXMLData :=  '<employees> <employee> <empno>7369</empno><ename>SMITH</ename> <job>CLERK</job> <hiredate>17-DEC-1980</hiredate> </employee>
             <employee><empno>7499</empno><ename>ALLEN</ename><job>SALESMAN</job><hiredate>20-FEB-1981</hiredate></employee></employees>';


            proc_parseXml_new(v_SessionId,  v_TransType, v_Operation , v_rawXMLData );
              end;

             /


        declare
            v_rawXMLData clob; 
            v_SessionId varchar2(20); 
            v_TransType varchar2(20); 
            v_Operation varchar2(20);
        begin
            v_TransType:='ADD';
            v_SessionId:='qwer1234';
            v_Operation:='CommitUpload';


         v_rawXMLData :=  '<employees> <employee> <empno>7369</empno><ename>SMITH</ename> <job>CLERK</job> <hiredate>17-DEC-1980</hiredate> </employee>
             <employee><empno>7499</empno><ename>ALLEN</ename><job>SALESMAN</job><hiredate>20-FEB-1981</hiredate></employee></employees>';


            proc_parseXml_new(v_SessionId,  v_TransType, v_Operation , v_rawXMLData );
        end;

        /
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYmgs.jpg)